# Row Aggregation value in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

How i can get the column C using big-query (Stucture of bigquery table is "id","revenue")

column C = Aggregate value of the revenue for each row

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzPew.jpg)

## id, revenue, C

1,  5,        5
2,  3,        8
3,  1,        9
4,  2,        11
5,  0,        11

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for, please elaborate

Comment: i need to find the column c using big query (cumulative sum)

Comment: See if my updated answer works.

Comment: Hi Elliott  when i try to use over (order by id) i face an error "Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory." Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, SUM(revenue) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS total_revenue
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
ORDER BY id
```

You can use below dummy data to test / play with it

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 5 revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0 
)
SELECT id, SUM(revenue) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS total_revenue
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
ORDER BY id
```

output is

```sql
id  total_revenue    
1   5    
2   8    
3   9    
4   11   
5   11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

If you also want the revenue total across all `id` values, you can use GROUP BY ROLLUP. The resulting row with a NULL `id` contains the total across all `id`s:

```
SELECT id, SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP(id)
ORDER BY id;
```

Edit: for a cumulative sum, you can use an analytic function. In this case, it would be:

```
SELECT id, SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS total_revenue
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY id;
```